# How do I define a function that calls on a module using a parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters, pynput

I am trying to use pynput to automate keyboard presses. With pynput, you must write a line for both pressing the key and releasing the key. I thought I would do this by defining a function like below.

```
keyboard = Controller()
def key_press(button):
   keyboard.press(Key.button)
   keyboard.release(Key.button)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work because I need to be able to call `keyboard.press(up)`. When I call the key_press function using key_press(up), it will throw a name error since "up" isn't defined as a variable. I cannot use `key_press("up")` either as it will then throw a syntax error. Is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: My bad. It is written `keyboard.press(up)` in my code but I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the lines inside the function with `keyboard.press(button)` and `keyboard.release(button)`, and I changed the function calls to `keyboard.press(Key.up)`. This somehow managed to make it work.